# AllowOveride All causes assetts and Admin Urls to 404

Tags: permalinks, images, admin

I had an issue with permalinks not working within wordpress and solved by adding below to my virtualhost file:

```
<Directory "/var/www/wordpress/public_html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

My htaccess is writable and updates when setting up permalinks within wordpress admin area and mod_rewrite is already enabled. The links update and start working for post name however all assets like `images` `css` `js` landing on 404 as well as admin links. How can this be solved?

Answer (score 2):

The step you're missing is to change the mod flag like so:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Also you'll need to change the .htaccess; refer to [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23388144/wordpress-apache-permalinks-not-working-404-error)

Comment: Yeah i googled this however that answer didnt fix for me. Mod_rewrite is enabled and im pretty sure that mod_rewrite isnt for allowing server to write to htaccess like in question you have posted. My htaccess is also writable and updated by wordpress when changing permalink settings within wordpress. Is there anything else im missing?

Comment: I don't think so. I had this problem when first installing and remember there were a few things I needed to do. Modify virtual host in Apache then enable rewrite. Did you restart Apache server?

Comment: Yeah it does work the acutal links for pages after restart but assetts just 404

Comment: There were a few steps. And I had same 404 problem. I googled and found resolution but I don't recall if there's a third thing to do

Comment: So i just reverted it and restart the apache and go back to normal links for now. I will have another google tommorow thanks for your help

Comment: Assets? I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: like css js,. images.

Comment: just end up with styless text but can see that rewrite working as they are not 404 pages for the seo friendly links.

Comment: This still isn't making sense. What is giving 404? You just said that's not the issue. I'm confused. Perhaps show screenshot

Comment: Did you install strangely in non standard directories?!

Comment: Its just images and css and JS all 404. The permalinks work now however broke the assetts. Its installed in folder /var/www/wordpress

Comment: No idea sorry. It's something you're okay expecting not related I'm betting